# steepest descent , Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, artificial-intelligence

```
f(x) = 4*(1-x(1)).^2 .* exp(-x(1).^2 - (x(2)+1).^2) - ...
    10*(x(1)/3 - x(1).^3 - x(2).^5 ) .* exp(-x(1).^2 - x(2).^2) - ...
    (1/2) .* exp(-(x(1)+1).^2 - x(2).^2)

where -5 <= x(1) <= 5 , -3 <= x(2) <= 3
```

I want to determine the optimal `x*` which maximizes `f(x)` using **steepest descent**.
I found http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ctk/darts/steep.m but I can't use it.
i don't understand this part of comment :

```
%  f = objective function,
%            the calling sequence for f should be
%            [fout,gout]=f(x) where fout=f(x) is a scalar
%              and gout = grad f(x) is a COLUMN vector
```

1. How can use this function?
2. How can modify initial conditions?
3. How can modify step sizes?

Comment: I am not sure steepest descent will be the best choice here. Steepest descent is usually used for a states with more then one dimension. Could you explain why you wish to use steepest descent and not any other method? it might shed some light on your actual problem...

Comment: its my home work,and i must use Steepest decent.

Comment: I suspect that you're expected to implement the steepest descent yourself. Otherwise, it's not very instructive. Have a go, then update the question with what you've tried.

Comment: @Nzbuu: you are right, I didn't use mathlab for a while and am not used to the fact that `x` could be a matrix/vector. Thanks.

Comment: my home work is: Determine the optimal x* which maximizes f(x) using steepest descent.
I. Try different initial conditions. What do you conclude?
II. Try different step sizes. For what value is it best?
Show the path of optimization on a 2-D plot of f(x) for each of above simulations. What do you conclude?

Comment: -1: The usage of a specific piece of code is not general enough. Also: no apparent attempt was made by question poster to solve it himself.

Comment: i tried to use http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ctk/darts/steep.m but i can't enter the parameter to use function.matlab error and i can't find the problem.

Comment: i don't understand this part of comment :   f = objective function,
%            the calling sequence for f should be
%            [fout,gout]=f(x) where fout=f(x) is a scalar
%              and gout = grad f(x) is a COLUMN vector

Comment: @naserghannad Everything in the steepest descent code is explained nicely. What have you tried so far, where is the exact problem?

Comment: i don't understand how convert my f(x) to f parameter for input function steepest decsent.

Comment: Look up "function handles" in the MATLAB help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to pass your function using a "function handle". Look it up in the help.
2. The initial conditions are the `x0` input.
3. The step sizes are chosen automatically.

Comment: hey,tnx for Good answer. i write this code : http://www.mediafire.com/?ku2r2bjzs8id6fs  but i can't handle error.